# Перехват/Блокировка исходяших с Node.js сервера запросов

Tags: node.js, http, веб-сервер, proxy, static

У меня есть простой файл index.html с функцией отправки запроса:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="sendReq()">
            Send request
        </button>
        <script>
            function sendReq() {
                axios.get("http://ip-api.com/json")
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Важно: в этом файле запросы можно отправлять не только методом axios, но и с помощью XMLHttpRequest и fetch.

А также у меня есть сервер, написанный на стандартном http из Node.js

```
const http = require("http"),
  proxy = require('node-global-proxy').default,
  fs = require("fs")

const PROXY_URL = "localhost:5050"
const SERVER_PORT = 5000
const PROXY_SRV_PORT = 5050

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`, (err, data) => {
    res.writeHead(200) 
    res.end(data)
  })
})

const proxy_srv = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log(`[proxy_srv] New req accepted. Url: ${req.url}`)
})

const test = async() => {
  proxy.system()
  proxy.setConfig({
    http: `http://${PROXY_URL}`,
    https: `https://${PROXY_URL}`
  })
  proxy.start() 

  // A request sent directly from the server is intercepted, but outgoing requests from [server] are not intercepted
  await http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
}

const bootstrap = () => {
  try { 
    server.listen(SERVER_PORT)
    proxy_srv.listen(PROXY_SRV_PORT) 
    console.log(`[server] Started on port ${SERVER_PORT} \n[proxy_srv] Started on port ${PROXY_SRV_PORT}`)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

bootstrap()
test()
```

Если вы запустите этот код, вы увидите что-то вроде:

```
[server] Started on port 5000
[proxy_srv] Started on port 5050
[proxy_srv] New req accepted. Url: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/
```

Но если вы попытаетесь отправить запрос в браузере с хоста http://localhost:5000/, то ничего не произойдет, и глобальный прокси не увидит *исходящих* с сервера запросов. Не мало важно то, что я делаю акцент именно на *исходящих* запросах.

Важно: у меня нет доступа к инициаторам запросов, поскольку я пытаюсь перехватывать/блокировать запросы, инициированные внутри iframe, поэтому мне нужен способ перехватить/блокировать его на максимально низком уровне, будь то этап инициации TCP-соединения или отправка запроса на сервер

Я понимаю, что делаю что-то не так. Я пытался использовать http.globalAgent, но я не понимаю, как использовать это, чтобы добавить прокси с полем URL моего прокси к каждому запросу, исходящему от сервера.

В реальности вместо маленького http сервера у меня огромный express сервер с кучей API, а вместо html файла у меня сборка react ts приложения, но так как сути проблемы это не меняет, Решил не грузить и без того раздутый вопрос

Буду бесконечно благодарен за любой ответ.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решением стало переписывание участков кода из iframe на сервере, и последующее встраивание переписанного кода в srcdoc фрейма.

Под "переписыванием" подразумевается перенаправление всех запросов из скрипта на
собственный прокси, а с него на конечную точку запроса. Такая система позволяет не сталкиваться с cors-ограничениями.

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю что с бека вы можете перехватывать сообщения клиента, если вы не подменили на клиенте сам axios или с чего выполняются запросы, если эти запросы направленные например на внешние ресурсы. Если запросы был наш сервер, то тут вопросов нет.
Почему вы вообще ожидаете что отдав клиенту разметку, вы сможете перехватить его запросы?

Как вариант можно собрать свой axios с таким же апи, и подключить к нему интерсептеры, при отдачи html, заменить axios на свой вариант.

Comment: Я так и думал, но мне надо перехватывать/блокировать запросы из iframe, а браузер не разрешает подключатся к dom фрейма, следственно выбор остается лишь один - попытатся перехватить запрос на уровне сервера

Comment: Речь о запросах из iframe, о каких запросах идет речь, любых? Iframe чей? Мне кажется вы хотите невозможное, так как просто  перехватить реквесты клиента просто так по одному желанию нельзя.

Comment: Iframe лежит на удаленном ресурсе, у меня нет доступа к коду этого фрейма